# Windows XP folder contains many folders with names like $NtUninstallKB842773$

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting $NtUninstall Folders from Windows directory](https://superuser.com/questions/103899/deleting-ntuninstall-folders-from-windows-directory)

In my Windows XP folder, there are many folders with names like `$NtUninstallKB842773$` and light yellow folder icons.

What are these folders? It seems that they have to do with the uninstall process. Can I delete these folders safely?

Answer (score 3):

These folders are part of the Windows update when Microsoft releases patches. They are stored in these folders as a backup place should you ever wish to uninstall them.

As long as you have no intention of uninstalling patches, then by all means go ahead and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

They allow you to uninstall Microsoft hotfixes and Windows Updates.  You should not delete them.

Answer (score 0):

This folder contains data that is necessary if a hotfix needs to be removed - in this case, [KB842773](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842773).  The light yellow folder indicates that they are normally hidden.  While you can safely delete them, if you do so, you will not be able to uninstall the hotfix in question.  The folder name `$NtUninstallKBxxxxxx$` refers to the Microsoft Knowledge Base item at `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/xxxxxx` (replace the `xxxxxx` with the actual number).  The folder name may be blue; if it is, the folder and its contents are compressed with NTFS compression to save disk space.