# Deleting $NtUninstall Folders from Windows directory

Tags: windows, file-management, uninstall

Can I safely delete old (i.e. 6 months or more) $NtUninstall folders from the Windows directory of my XP box?

**EDIT**: thanks for the feedback everyone - does this also apply to the stuff in `C:\WINDOWS\Installer`?

Related:

- [Can I delete the folder "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\$PatchCache$"?](https://superuser.com/questions/82578/can-i-delete-the-folder-c-windows-installer-patchcache)
- [Is it safe to delete from C:\Windows\Installer?](https://superuser.com/questions/23479/is-it-safe-to-delete-from-c-windows-installer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those folders are associated with updates from Microsoft. If you delete them, you won't be able to uninstall the updates regularly, which you probably don't want to uninstall them anyways for security reasons!

So the bottom line is, if you don't plan on deleting the updates, it's safe to delete the folders.

Comment: so that's a "yes, I can delete them", then? (it's late and that's one too many double-negatives for me at this time of night) :)

Comment: You sure can! :)

Comment: +1 - some people say not recommended but I agree with you that they can be deleted. In addition, worst case scenario, you can use System Restore to remove the last few updates